# Enabling AllShare Cast in an Android App

Tags: android, samsung-smart-tv, screensharing

I'm developing a very simple application where I have a button .. OnClicking that button the screen of my mobile phone should be shared with my Smart Samsung TV. The question now is how can I enable AllShare Cast feature onClicking that button??

from what I read, I should create an AllShare app from the beginning (see: http://developer.samsung.com/allshare-framework/start) .. but I want to implement this using a normal Android Application.

Appreciate your tips

Comment: AFAIK, AllShare Cast is the same as Miracast, which means on Android 4.2 you can use `Presentation` to customize what gets displayed, versus the default mirroring.

Comment: Have you followed all the steps from that link? It will install all the required tools to develop an Android app with support for AllShare.

Comment: As you can see from the link, after installing the SDK, I should create a new "AllShare project". I don't want to do so, I want to enable this feature in the "Android Project" I'm working on. I mean I don't want to change the project type.

Comment: @CommonsWare You are right. AllShare Cast is the moniker used by Samsung for Miracast http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miracast

Comment: to enable the wifi from my app we write this wifiManager = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true); I want to use the same technique to enable the all sharecast

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the `activateManagerUI()` method to enable the AllShare Cast.

[Link to the `activateManagerUI()` javadoc.](http://img-developer.samsung.com/onlinedocs/ASF_API_Reference_1_0/com/sec/android/allshare/screen/ScreenCastManager.html#activateManagerUI%28%29)

I know that it is not the solution you asked for, but as far I know you can't enable the AllShare Cast without asking user to do that.